# grep: regular expression to search all but not

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I was curious, how many [BibTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) entries I gathered in the last decades.  So I said to myself: "lets hack a quick script for that!"

To those not familiar with BibTeX: each entry starts with an type identifier such as `@book`, `@article`, `@incollection` and so on.  Actually, there are more than 50 different tpye identifier defined, but this might expand in the future?  Usually (but not necessarily) this identifiers are placed right at the beginning of the line.  So my regexp No. 1 should contain `[[:space:]]*@\w+` to match the starting line of an entry.

Unfortunately, there are three identfier, which do **not** start a bibliography source: `@comment`, `@string` and `@preamble`.  I occasionally use some of them in my files.  To match these, I should write regexp  No. 2 like `@((comment)|(string)|(preamble))`, which works fine and matches well.

But the last three expressions should not be counted as bibliography items and therefore my final regular expression should read like "find all Regexp of No. 1 but not of No. 2"

This is, where I failed to combined these two regexp groups.  I solved it by piping two regexp, the second one using the switch `-v` to invert the results, but I am sure, there is a way, to write this in one regexp.

Comment: I think the answer is negative look-ahead, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex

Comment: You don't lose much by running a second `grep` with `-v` in a pipeline.  It may even be easier to understand whenever you re-read your code in a year's time.

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't want to count `@((comment)|(string)|(preamble))`, then why include it? Why not just search for `@book`, `@article` or any other specific headers you do want to count? Are there too many to list easily?

Comment: @terdon There are too many and in the recent years, the list has grown substantially.  The actual handbook lists 58 different types.  So the ratio is 58 wanted vs. three unwanted.

Comment: @they You are so right.  I guess, I won't need a year, not even a quarter year, to forget my glorious regexp ;-)  On the other hand: I am really bad in constructing regexp and hence, it is my new years resolution, to practice regexp wherever I have the chance.  You see, I must solve this in one regexp.

Comment: @Jan I see, fair enough. You might want to add that to the question since I thought you only had `@book`.

Comment: @terdon thanks again, edited it.  It is now more precise and clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [negative look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to not match `@` when `comment`, `string` or `preamble` (or anything starting with these strings) follows:

```bsh
grep -P '^[[:space:]]*@(?!comment|string|preamble)\w' file
```

Comment: If you don't anchor the regexp (nor use `-o`), the `[[:space:]]*` and the `+` are superfluous.

Comment: True true, I just took OPs regex. Edited

Comment: More like `grep -P '^\s*@(?!...)\w'` I'd think.

Comment: Maybe. OP didn't provide an input example, so I just took his regex ...

Comment: See https://www.bibtex.com/g/bibtex-format/ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX

Comment: Likely not a problem for the OP, but it may be worth noting that it would also exclude `@stringy` or `@commentary` tags.

Comment: @pLumo Thank you very much.  This worked for me, I learned something new.  As always: look ahead! ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Actually, `@stingy` isn't defined and I doubt, it will ever by, so this matches aren't a problem.  But who knows, what the future brings?

Comment: Something like this could do then: `^[[:space:]]*@(?!(comment|string|preamble)($|[^\w]))\w`